# If,Elseif, else with multiple queries returning zero value

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, return-value

So i've run into a little problem, i have a script that returns a false BOOL when it should be returning a true BOOL. Can anyone tell me where the error is?

```
Elseif(isset($_POST['Submit_VO']) && '$_GET[Aflever]' == 1);{
    $MAdelete = $_SESSION['MA_NR'];
    $Bunni = "SELECT Bunny_No FROM Bunnies_final";
    $QueryingBunni= Mysqli_query($conn,$Bunni);
    $Take = "SELECT Bunny_No, Laaner, Ordre_No FROM Udlaan WHERE Bunny_No = '$Bunni' AND Laaner = $MAdelete";
    $Querying = Mysqli_query($conn,$Take);
    var_dump($Take);
    print_r($Take);
    If(!$Querying == 1){
        Echo "Du har ingen lånte instrumenter";
    }
    Else{
        $Delete ="UPDATE Bunnies_final Laaner = NULL, Ordre_No = NULL WHERE Bunny_No = $Take[Bunny_No] AND" ;
    }
   exit();
}
```

What is script is doing is a Borrow/return script for the return process (I'm positive that the rest of the code works).

Quick rundown of what should be happening: `$_POST['Submit_VO']` is a button that is unclickable without filling out 2 inputfields. It is then required for this process to tick a checkbox (`$_GET[Aflever]`)
Well that is what you need to know from me, the rest is in the script.

Right now i am getting a zero value from

```
If(!$Querying == 1){
   Echo "Du har ingen lånte instrumenter";
}Else{
   $Delete ="UPDATE Bunnies_final Laaner = NULL, Ordre_No = NULL WHERE Bunny_No = $Take[Bunny_No] AND" ;
 }
 exit();
 }
```

I know this since i see the echo, which means that `$Querying`is causing the problem, but i can't see it.

FYI i know that the code is flawed against SQL injection. But it's not importantant since it's a standalone system with minimal user input.

Comment: Why not `$Querying != 1` instead of `!$Querying == 1`?

Comment: The first thing i thought of after i clicked 'post' was that i might need to store the first query in a variable and use that variable in `$Take` where `$Bunni` is.

Comment: @SougataBose in my eyes in essentially the same math

Comment: what is the value of `$Querying` in your test?

Comment: @BizzyBob i would tell you if i could. I can't seem to get nothing from the script now (var_dump, print_r)

Comment: `$Querying != 1` would return `boolean`. And you are first getting the boolean value then applying negation. Adding 1 extra step.

Comment: @SougataBose Could you elaborate why `$Querying !=1` would return a true bool

Comment: i'm getting this error message: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in line 204. Which is the line where $Take is stated.

Comment: I have localized the error. It seems that my script above this one (I haven't shown you) is messing with me. I have an if statement identical to to one on the first line. It seems that when the initial button is pressed    `$_POST['Submit_VO']` it drops the checkbox `'$_GET[aflever]'` and the script never gets started. I might be able to fix it with a strpos.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is cleaner to say $Querying != 1.

Then, the query is wrong:

```
$Take = "SELECT Bunny_No, Laaner, Ordre_No FROM Udlaan WHERE Bunny_No = '$Bunni' AND Laaner = $MAdelete";
```

$Bunni is basically "SELECT Bunny_No FROM Bunnies_final", not the outcome of the query.

You can change it to:

```
$Take = "SELECT Bunny_No, Laaner, Ordre_No FROM Udlaan WHERE Bunny_No = '".$QueryingBunni['Bunny_No']."' AND Laaner = $MAdelete";
```